# NetLogo- randomness in the list to identify turtles in the neighbohood

Tags: netlogo

I would like to get the sum of specific weights only in patches with turtles present in its respective moore neighborhood.  My approach is develop a sum of products between a list of weight and a list of binary variables. I created a list of weights in the neighborhood for each patch

```
Let weight_list [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]; weights of the moore neighborhood for specific patch
```

Then, I created a list with a binary variable (1 if turtle is present in a neighbor patch, 0 otherwise),

```
ask patches with [  any?  turtles-here ]   [let turtle_present 1 ]
ask patches with [ not any? turtles-here]  [let turtle_present 0 ]
ask patches[ set binary_list  [ turtle_present ] of neighbors ]
```

I tried to multiply this binary_list with their respective weights and get the sum, e.g.
`sum (binary_list * weight_list)`

My problem is that the binary_list is sorted in random order. E.g. if I have 2 turtles in the neighborhood the list can show [01100000] or [01000100]. This randomness does not allow me to multiply with their respective weights. This may be a dumb question but I am relative new user of NetLogo. I will appreciate any help, Thanks

Comment: Which weight should correspond to which neighbor?

Comment: Each weight number correspond to the cardinal directions of moore neighborhood [1=NW, 2= W, 3=SW, 4=S, 5=SE, 6=E, 7=NE and 8=N], For example if I have a turtle in the north and south of a specific patch, I would like to get as an output [8+4]=12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not a stupid question. Working with sorted lists of agents usually requires a little bit of a workaround, and it's not always particularly intuitive.

If you sort patches, they will come out sorted from the top left corner, filling out rows from left to right. So take that into account for your `weight-list`. Since we can't ask lists to do things like we can with agentsets, we will need to iterate over the list with `map`, asking each patch to report its neighbors.

There are a bunch of different ways of doing that, but my suggestion would be to write a reporter along the lines of this:

```
to-report neighbor-list
  report map [[ifelse-value any? turtles-here [1][0]] of ?]
             sort neighbors
end
```

At this point you can simply ask a patch (or a turtle, since they have direct access to 'their' patch's variables) for their neighbor-list, and it will send you a list of 1s and 0s in a consistent order.

Comment: Thanks Arthur for your reply, but I can not see how this can help me. Using your code I got a list of [11111111] for patches with turtles and a list of zeros for patches without turtles. It does not report the neighbors patches with turtles in a consistent order.

Comment: Sorry, the ```'myself'``` should have been a ```'self'```. However, Seth's edited code with ```map``` is a much cleaner solution. Thanks @SethTisue!

Comment: Thanks both for your time.It works great,but in order to multiply with the weight_list, I needed to sort also my weightList. I did using this line of 'code': let weights_sorted map [ [ weight-list ] of ? ] sort neighbors